# how to take branch name as choice parameter and in 2nd parameter populate branches dynamically so user can select a branch in a jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

We have a job called version-prep which do multiple tasks, 
1. update pom with next version.
2. mark version as released in jira.
3. create new tag in jira.
4. promote artifact from CI to dev infra.

For this we take user input for below 5 parameters.

```
1. serviceName  (Choice parameter)  
2. branch   (String)
 3. buildnumber(String) ( Example - if build is 1.1.1-5, so value need to be provided is 5  )
4. repository   (Choice parameter)
5. version (string)(Example - if build is 1.1.1-5, so value need to be provided is 1.1.1    )
6. jiraName (Choice parameter)
```

I want to populate branches in this section automatically for the service which user will select from above service name. I tried git parameter plugin but it wants hardcore repo name inside job for which it can show branches as drop down list. 
Here, we want something different for which i am not finding anyway to do it..

Can anyone help me how to achieve it..

Comment: Google 1st, you can find many things before post here: https://medium.com/@g4b1s/dynamically-list-git-branches-in-jenkins-job-parameter-3e6e849f8a98

Comment: You can have a file with the version name in the repo and read it, so you won't need to ask for `version`. Also, you can use Jenkins Build number as `buildnumber` so you don't have to ask for that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Plugin: Git Parameter 
Pluginhttps://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin